# GTKmm + cairo app for real-time graphics freezes often

Tags: c++, graphics, gtk, cairo, gtkmm3

I'm writing a C++ application whose main window needs to **receive real-time data from a server and draw plots and histograms in realtime** based on this data. I'm using GTK3 (actually its C++ binding gtkmm) and Cairo.

In particular, data is received every 1 second from the network, and refresh happens every time the data is received, thus every 1 second. Refresh is done by calling the ***invalidate_rect() method for the entire drawing area***, whose on_draw() even redraws all figures and plots using the newly received data.

Now, the application works but it's **extremely unreliable**. In particular, it freezes very often, especially when the CPU load increases. The CPU usage of my application, as well as memory, are very low. Suddenly the window becomes grey and unresponsive, and I need to kill it with Ctrl-C, since even pressing the window close icon doesn't work.

I'm wondering: is it the wrong approach to call invalidate_rect() in the scenario above? What is a better way, using GTKMM/Cairo, to obtain smooth graphics in a reliable way?

Comment: What is your thread structure? Can you somehow integrate the server polls into the GTK+ main loop using GIO? Also why `invalidate_rect()` and not `queue_draw_area()`? And redrawing more than you need can lead to speed issues; since you were already using `invalidate_rect()` you should have only passed the part you needed to update.

Comment: The main thread (which blocks on `app->run(win)`) spawns another one that receives the data from the network (once per second) and calls the `invalidate_rect()` for the drawing area every time. The entire drawing area need to be redrawn as it is packed with dynamically changing figures. Tried `queue_draw_area()` instead, but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You can't call `queue_draw_area()` from the other thread. You need to queue it to run on the GTK+ thread. In plain C this would be done with `gdk_threads_add_idle()`, but I don't know what it would be with gtkmm.

Comment: Thanks @andlabs  that solved the problem. By calling the `invalidate_rect()` from the main thread (via a periodic timer event) the application is now very stable.